# Download file from server extjs with error message on fail

Tags: html, forms, download, extjs5

I am using extjs-5 and want to download file from server. I have implemented the code that works well for normal case but when server throws an error at that time my application redirect to another page to display server thrown error.

```
                Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                    standardSubmit: true,

                }).getForm().submit({
                        url: url,
                        fileUpload:true,
                        params: params,
                        success: function (response, opts) {
                            if (successCallBack) {
                                successCallBack.call(scope, response, opts);
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function (form, action) {
                            if (failureCallback) {
                                failureCallback.call(scope, form, action);
                            }
                        }

                    });
```

In normal case I am able to download file but when server throws any error that time I want to display that message instead redirect to another page.